# AWS-CDK Pipelines trigger deployment from local terminal

Tags: amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, aws-cdk

Currently I'm using `@aws-cdk/pipelines` package for quick and easy setup of CI/CD for my service.

However during the experimentation/development phase, I would like to manually call `cdk deploy` for my stack with business logic components, so the deployment loop would be a lot faster, as I don't need pipeline self-mutation steps and also I don't want to push everything to repository each time.

Unfortunately I'm not able to achieve this. After trying to call manually `npx cdk deploy` command in the repository root folder, it's simply deploying the stack, that contains the pipeline resources.

I was also trying to achieve this by calling stack name directly:

```
npx cdk deploy -c config=dev <full-stack-name>
```

And it fails with `No stacks match the name(s) [...]` message.

Is this possible? I believe it's quite important use case, since deploying through proper CI/CD pipeline takes at least 2-3 minutes and it ruins my focus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new, [plain vanilla app](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/stacks.html) to handle the standalone, non-pipeline deploy scenario:

```js
// bin/dev-app.ts
const app = new cdk.App();
new MyBusinessLogicStack(app, 'DevStack', props)
```

Tell the CLI to deploy the `dev-app` with an explicit [app command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/cli.html#cli-app-command):

```sh
cdk deploy --app 'npx ts-node bin/dev-app.ts'
```

You now have two "apps": one that deploys the pipeline and the new one that deploys a standalone "business logic stack".

Comment: Is this really needed, though? You can just deploy the stages/stacks manually, the key is to supply the correct name.

Comment: @gshpychka  Not strictly necessary, but it does have advantages for development use cases.  A dev env deployed as a separate app:  (1) can be deployed in isolation without touching the pipeline-linked production env;  (2) can be configured to use cheaper resources; and (3) is compatible with [watch mode](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/cli.html#cli-deploy-watch) for faster deploy iterations.

Comment: (1) and (3) still applies to deploying the Pipeline's infra stacks manually, doesn't it?

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to creating a separate app, you can also deploy the stacks directly. To get the stack name, use `cdk ls`. It will be `<Pipeline Name>/<Stage Name>/<Stack name>`.

Also, you can deploy the whole stage manually with

```sh
cdk deploy "<Pipeline Name>/<Stage Name>"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Codestar as the source of your pipeline, you can point it toward a specific branch in your repo of choice. Then just commit your code to  said branch and this will trigger your pipeline.

I do recommend as other answers however, and keeping your Pipeline Stack and your App stack separate - you can make use of cdk-pipelines to auto update your stack (self mutating) if you desire, but for rapid development having your app as its own stack is best. - not only is it safer, you can use cdk watch now to have it auto deploy changes, skipping the pipeline entirely.